# How can I see average of raster value over certain area, marked by mouse?

Tags: qgis, raster

I have a raster in Quantum GIS and I am just exploring it. How can I see average of raster value over certain area, marked by mouse? In other words:

1. How can I select particular area in QGIS?
2. How can I compute average of raster value over that area?

Answer (score 1):

You should try [Zonal Statistics plugin](http://docs.qgis.org/1.8/html/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins_zonal_statistics.html).

[image]

Comment: thank you. What about the question 1, i.e. pure area selection? This must be very simple, but I am new to QGIS.

Comment: create a polygon

Comment: There's no simpler way of making a rectangle selection? Even MS Paint can do this :-)

Comment: It is quite simple. More 'simpler' way will require custom tool. QGIS is open-source. You can create and add any tool you need on your own. So go ahead and create one )))

Comment: I cannot find this plugin in `Plugins > Fetch python plugins`. I have QGIS version 1.9.0-Master. Any tips?

Comment: Look more carefully. I have it. See updated answer.

Comment: Aha, so it is kind of internal plugin, that just has to be enabled ... thanks! I have it enabled now. But how do I access it? I cannot find it in menus.

Comment: @Tomas raster toolbar, if I remember correctly

Answer (score 0):

The select tool can be seen here. If you click on the drop down you can change the method used to select (rectangle, freehand etc):
[image]

Comment: this won't help as the select tool is for vector layers only

Comment: for the raster sure, but if he were to vectorise the data it would be a handy tool for a 'rectangle selection' i think?

Comment: Then edit your answer to point out all the steps. But note that the question is over 5months old and the OP probably already found a solution